# GridView, RowDataBound event executing twice for each row

Tags: asp.net

I have a GridView that is using an SQLDataSource to bind to a database.

For some reason my RowDataBound event on the GridView is executing twice.

Why is this happening?

Comment: fist increase refresh time duration to considerable time like 5min and check whether same behavior exist or not

Comment: Still happens even with a 10 minute interval

Comment: Check whether you are handling `RowDataBound` event twice in your code.

Comment: No I just have `onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound"` in my GridView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that if you enable the Footer in your GridView from your code behind (gv.ShowFooter = true;) and it was not previously set to true, it will rebind the data.  This seems like a bug to me!

Instead I enabled the footer in my .aspx file and all is good.